# Swapping column values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL table with coordinates; the column names are X and Y. Now I want to swap the column values in this table, so that X becomes Y and Y becomes X. The most apparent solution would be renaming the columns, but I don't want to make structure changes since I don't necessarily have permissions to do that.

Is this possible to do with **UPDATE** in some way? **UPDATE table SET X=Y, Y=X** obviously won't do what I want.

---

Please note that my restriction on permissions, mentioned above, effectively prevents the use of ALTER TABLE or other commands that change the table/database structure. Renaming columns or adding new ones are unfortunately not options.

Comment: as a note, `UPDATE table SET X = Y, Y = X` is the standard way of doing it in SQL, only MySQL misbehaves.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

I just had to deal with the same and I'll summarize my findings.

1. The `UPDATE table SET X=Y, Y=X` approach obviously doesn't work, as it'll just set both values to Y.
2. Here's a method that uses a temporary variable. Thanks to Antony from the comments of http://beerpla.net/2009/02/17/swapping-column-values-in-mysql/ for the "IS NOT NULL" tweak. Without it, the query works unpredictably. See the table schema at the end of the post. This method doesn't swap the values if one of them is NULL. Use method #3 that doesn't have this limitation.

   `UPDATE swap_test SET x=y, y=@temp WHERE (@temp:=x) IS NOT NULL;`
3. This method was offered by Dipin in, yet again, the comments of http://beerpla.net/2009/02/17/swapping-column-values-in-mysql/. I think it’s the most elegant and clean solution. It works with both NULL and non-NULL values.

   `UPDATE swap_test SET x=(@temp:=x), x = y, y = @temp;`
4. Another approach I came up with that seems to work:

   `UPDATE swap_test s1, swap_test s2 SET s1.x=s1.y, s1.y=s2.x WHERE s1.id=s2.id;`

Essentially, the 1st table is the one getting updated and the 2nd one is used to pull the old data from.
Note that this approach requires a primary key to be present.

This is my test schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `swap_test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `x` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `y` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `swap_test` VALUES ('1', 'a', '10');
INSERT INTO `swap_test` VALUES ('2', NULL, '20');
INSERT INTO `swap_test` VALUES ('3', 'c', NULL);
```

Comment: As noted in MySQL docs, It's not safe to assign and read variables in a single statement. The order of operations is not guaranteed.
So the only safe method is #4

Comment: Option 4 worked for me.  You can obviously add more conditions to the where clause if you need to swap the columns for only some rows.

Comment: You know, I never thought there'd be a practical use for that stupid interview question asking to swap two variables without using a temporary, but here it is, and for integers this would actually work: update swap_test set x=x+y,y=x-y,x=x-y;

Comment: Most of this answer is direct copy/paste from http://beerpla.net/2009/02/17/swapping-column-values-in-mysql/

Comment: @Jhawins That's because beerpla.net is my blog.

Comment: I would just do `update swap_test set x=if(@old_x:=x,y,y),y=@old_x;`

Comment: Your answers made me know it was feasible and your approach #4 is exactly what i needed. This was more insight full then the mysql manual.

Comment: It is 22:30, I just ran a bulk product insert on a live DB serving 100K+ users. I swapped the column names around by mistake and was not happy about the fact that I had to now sit and figure out a way to fix this, so I came here instead. You just gave me exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, and the op sincerely.

Comment: Since the order of the column setting is not guaranteed, use option 4, but also change it to read: `UPDATE swap_test s1 JOIN swap_test s2 USING(id) SET s1.x=s2.y, s1.y=s2.x;`  The way it was presented will go wrong if the columns are assigned other than left-to-right. By using s2 twice you solve that, Also, using a join should be a tad quicker.

Comment: Why did I need to scroll so much to find this answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 63):

You could take the sum and subtract the opposing value using X and Y

```
UPDATE swaptest SET X=X+Y,Y=X-Y,X=X-Y;
```

Here is a sample test (and it works with negative numbers)

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> drop table if exists swaptest;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> create table swaptest (X int,Y int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO swaptest VALUES (1,2),(3,4),(-5,-8),(-13,27);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.08 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM swaptest;
+------+------+
| X    | Y    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |
|    3 |    4 |
|   -5 |   -8 |
|  -13 |   27 |
+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is the swap being performed

```
mysql> UPDATE swaptest SET X=X+Y,Y=X-Y,X=X-Y;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.07 sec)
Rows matched: 4  Changed: 4  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM swaptest;
+------+------+
| X    | Y    |
+------+------+
|    2 |    1 |
|    4 |    3 |
|   -8 |   -5 |
|   27 |  -13 |
+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a try!!!

Comment: For the numbers it's indeed a neatest one.

Comment: Might be a problem if a value overflows when add?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve perhaps for `TINYINT` or huge valules of `INT`, you are right !!!

Comment: I'd use XOR to swap two values https://betterexplained.com/articles/swap-two-variables-using-xor/

Answer (score 52):

The following code works for all scenarios in my quick testing:

```
UPDATE swap_test
   SET x=(@temp:=x), x = y, y = @temp
```

Comment: `UPDATE table swap_test`? Shouldn't it be `UPDATE swap_test`?

Comment: Thank you. This worked like a charm on MySql 8.0.23 and MySql 5.7.31

Comment: Do the parentheses ensure that `@temp` is set prior to any other operations being performed? (MySQL doesn't always set variables in the order defined by the `UPDATE` statement, so I want to be sure).

Comment: While a simple [TEST](https://dbfiddle.uk/Oq06G0oQ) works, you still do get a warning: "**Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.**", which should not be ignored.

Answer (score 14):

**UPDATE table SET X=Y, Y=X** will do precisely what you want (in PostgreSQL, not MySQL, see below). The values are taken from the old row and assigned to a new copy of the same row, then the old row is replaced. You do not have to resort to using a temporary table, a temporary column, or other swap tricks.

@D4V360: I see. That is shocking and unexpected. I use PostgreSQL and my answer works correctly there (I tried it). See the [PostgreSQL UPDATE docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-update.html) (under Parameters, expression), where it mentions that expressions on the right hand side of SET clauses explicitly use the old values of columns. I see that the corresponding [MySQL UPDATE docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/6.0/en/update.html) contain the statement "Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right" which implies the behaviour you describe.

Good to know.

Comment: Thanks Greg and D4V360, good to know the differences in PostgreSQL and MySQL about the behavior of the update queries.

Comment: The "x=y, y=x" approach also works in Oracle, for what it's worth.

Comment: I used PostgreSQL and SET X=Y, Y=X  saved me :)

Comment: IMHO this answer is a mess - bad advice with "oops never mind" appended. Half of it should be a comment and the only part of the remainder that's relevant to the question is the link to MySQL docs...

Answer (score 7):

Ok, so just for fun, you could do this! (assuming you're swapping string values)

```
mysql> select * from swapper;
+------+------+
| foo  | bar  |
+------+------+
| 6    | 1    |
| 5    | 2    |
| 4    | 3    |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update swapper set
    -> foo = concat(foo, "###", bar),
    -> bar = replace(foo, concat("###", bar), ""),
    -> foo = replace(foo, concat(bar, "###"), "");

Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from swapper;
+------+------+
| foo  | bar  |
+------+------+
| 1    | 6    |
| 2    | 5    |
| 3    | 4    |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

A nice bit of fun abusing the left-to-right evaluation process in MySQL.

Alternatively, just use XOR if they're numbers. You mentioned coordinates, so do you have lovely integer values, or complex strings?

The XOR stuff works like this by the way:

```
update swapper set foo = foo ^ bar, bar = foo ^ bar, foo = foo ^ bar;
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe having an intermediate exchange variable is the best practice in such way:

```
update z set c1 = @c := c1, c1 = c2, c2 = @c
```

First, it works always; second, it works regardless of data type.

In spite of *both*

```
update z set c1 = c1 ^ c2, c2 = c1 ^ c2, c1 = c1 ^ c2
```

and

```
update z set c1 = c1 + c2, c2 = c1 - c2, c1 = c1 - c2
```

are working usually. Only for number data type by the way, and it is your responsibility to prevent overflow. You can not use XOR between signed and unsigned, and you also can not use sum for the overflowing possibility.

And

```
update z set c1 = c2, c2 = @c where @c := c1
```

is not working if c1 is 0 or NULL or zero length string or just spaces.

We need change it to

```
update z set c1 = c2, c2 = @c where if((@c := c1), true, true)
```

Here are the scripts:

```
mysql> create table z (c1 int, c2 int)
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into z values(0, 1), (-1, 1), (pow(2, 31) - 1, pow(2, 31) - 2)
    -> ;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from z;
+------------+------------+
| c1         | c2         |
+------------+------------+
|          0 |          1 |
|         -1 |          1 |
| 2147483647 | 2147483646 |
+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> update z set c1 = c1 ^ c2, c2 = c1 ^ c2, c1 = c1 ^ c2;
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'c1' at row 2
mysql> update z set c1 = c1 + c2, c2 = c1 - c2, c1 = c1 - c2;
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'c1' at row 3

mysql> select * from z;
+------------+------------+
| c1         | c2         |
+------------+------------+
|          0 |          1 |
|          1 |         -1 |
| 2147483646 | 2147483647 |
+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> update z set c1 = c2, c2 = @c where @c := c1;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from z;
+------------+------------+
| c1         | c2         |
+------------+------------+
|          0 |          1 |
|         -1 |          1 |
| 2147483647 | 2147483646 |
+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from z;
+------------+------------+
| c1         | c2         |
+------------+------------+
|          1 |          0 |
|          1 |         -1 |
| 2147483646 | 2147483647 |
+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update z set c1 = @c := c1, c1 = c2, c2 = @c;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from z;
+------------+------------+
| c1         | c2         |
+------------+------------+
|          0 |          1 |
|         -1 |          1 |
| 2147483647 | 2147483646 |
+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>update z set c1 = c2, c2 = @c where if((@c := c1), true, true);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from z;
+------------+------------+
| c1         | c2         |
+------------+------------+
|          1 |          0 |
|          1 |         -1 |
| 2147483646 | 2147483647 |
+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: +1 for finally finding a good use for the stupid interview question where you have to swap two variables without a temporary ;-)

Answer (score 6):

As other answers point out, **a simple swap won't work with MySQL** because it caches the value of column 1 *immediately* before processing column 2, resulting in both columns being set to the value of column 2.

Given that the order of operations is not guaranteed in MySQL, using a temporary variable is also not reliable.

The only safe way to swap two columns without modifying the table structure is with an inner join, which requires a primary key (`id` in this case).

```
UPDATE mytable t1, mytable t2
SET t1.column1 = t1.column2,
    t1.column2 = t2.column1
WHERE t1.id = t2.id;
```

**This will work without any issues.**

Answer (score 5):

`ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN tmp;
UPDATE table SET tmp = X;
UPDATE table SET X = Y;
UPDATE table SET Y = tmp;
ALTER TABLE table DROP COLUMN tmp;`

Something like this?

About [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill)'s comment:
No, this doesn't work:

```
mysql> select * from test;
+------+------+
| x    | y    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |
|    3 |    4 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update test set x=y, y=x;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test;
+------+------+
| x    | y    |
+------+------+
|    2 |    2 |
|    4 |    4 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Just for the record: This *does* work in PostgreSQL while it does *not* work in MySQL.

Comment: Re *"Greg's comment"*: Do you mean Greg's answer? Or was the comment deleted?

Answer (score 4):

Two alternatives

1. Use a temporary table
2. Investigate the [XOR algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried it, but

```
UPDATE tbl SET @temp=X, X=Y, Y=@temp
```

Might do it.

Answer (score 2):

This surely works! I've just needed it to swap Euro and SKK price columns. :)

```
UPDATE tbl SET X=Y, Y=@temp where @temp:=X;
```

The above will not work (ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax)

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you can use this query:

```sql
update swaptable 
set col1 = t2.col2,
col2 = t2.col1
from swaptable t2
where id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have signed integers in your columns, you may need to use CAST(a ^ b AS SIGNED), since the result of the ^ operator is an unsigned 64-bit integer in MySQL.

In case it helps anyone, here's the method I used to swap the same column between two given rows:

```
SELECT BIT_XOR(foo) FROM table WHERE key = $1 OR key = $2

UPDATE table SET foo = CAST(foo ^ $3 AS SIGNED) WHERE key = $1 OR key = $2
```

where $1 and $2 are the keys of two rows and $3 is the result of the first query.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* change column names, but this is more of a hack. But be cautious of any indexes that may be on these columns.

Answer (score 1):

**Table name is customer.** 
**fields are a and b, swap a value to b;.**

**UPDATE customer  SET a=(@temp:=a), a = b, b = @temp**

I checked this is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to swap the value of first and last name in tb_user.

The safest would be:

1. Copy tb_user. So you will have 2 tables: tb_user and tb_user_copy
2. Use UPDATE INNER JOIN query

```sql
UPDATE tb_user a
INNER JOIN tb_user_copy b
ON a.id = b.id
SET a.first_name = b.last_name, a.last_name = b.first_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the below query. It worked perfect for me.

```
Table name: studentname
only single column available: name


update studentnames
set names = case names
when "Tanu" then "dipan"
when "dipan" then "Tanu"
end;

or

update studentnames
set names = case names
when "Tanu" then "dipan"
else "Tanu"
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Swapping of column values using a single query:

```
UPDATE my_table SET a=@tmp:=a, a=b, b=@tmp;
```

Comment: This is just a repeat of #3 of [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/559291/1402846).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Names
(
F_NAME VARCHAR(22),
L_NAME VARCHAR(22)
);

INSERT INTO Names VALUES('Ashutosh', 'Singh'),('Anshuman','Singh'),('Manu', 'Singh');

UPDATE Names N1 , Names N2 SET N1.F_NAME = N2.L_NAME , N1.L_NAME = N2.F_NAME 
WHERE N1.F_NAME = N2.F_NAME;

SELECT * FROM Names;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to just move a value from one column to the other (like archiving) and reset the value of the original column. 
The below (reference of #3 from the accepted answer) worked for me.

```
Update MyTable set X= (@temp:= X), X = 0, Y = @temp WHERE ID= 999;
```

Answer (score 0):

This example swaps **start_date** and **end_date** for records where the dates are the wrong way round (when performing ETL into a major rewrite, I found some **start** dates later than their **end** dates.  Down, bad programmers!).

In situ, I'm using MEDIUMINTs for performance reasons (like Julian days, but having a 0 root of 1900-01-01), so I was OK doing a condition of **WHERE mdu.start_date > mdu.end_date**.

The PKs were on all 3 columns individually (for operational / indexing reasons).

```
UPDATE monitor_date mdu
INNER JOIN monitor_date mdc
    ON mdu.register_id = mdc.register_id
    AND mdu.start_date = mdc.start_date
    AND mdu.end_date = mdc.end_date
SET mdu.start_date = mdu.end_date, mdu.end_date = mdc.start_date
WHERE mdu.start_date > mdu.end_date;
```

Comment: FYI: This code updated 145 / 108,456 records in 0.203 secs.
It was a one off task and so performance was not critical.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to swap all the columns where x is to y and y to x, use this query:

`UPDATE table_name SET column_name = CASE column_name WHERE 'value of col is x' THEN 'swap it to y' ELSE 'swap it to x' END;`

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine this table and let's try to swap the m and f from the 'sex' table:

| id | name | sex | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | m | 2500 |
| 2 | B | f | 1500 |
| 3 | C | m | 5500 |
| 4 | D | f | 500 |

```
UPDATE sex
SET sex = CASE sex
WHEN 'm' THEN 'f'
ELSE 'm'
END;
```

So the updated table becomes:

| id | name | sex | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | f | 2500 |
| 2 | B | m | 1500 |
| 3 | C | f | 5500 |
| 4 | D | m | 500 |

Comment: This allows swapping values within a column. It does not help with the question where they need to be swapped across columns.