# How to swap the column values for 2 records in a table?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I'm trying to swap a column value for 2 records in a table. 
I have a primary key: 'recnr'

```
 Recnr   File 
 1     img001.jpg 
 2     img002.jpg 
 5     img005.jpg 
 6     img006.jpg
```

I want the file img005.jpg to move up one place to be:

```
 Recnr   File 
 1       img001.jpg
 2       img005.jpg
 5       img002.jpg
 6       img006.jpg
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Seems like a bad idea on the surface. Can you provide some background on why you need to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649/swapping-column-values-in-mysql

Comment: i need this to change positions.. @Damp: tnx for this

Comment: Oh you reformatted the post, I had the question wrong... sorry about that

Comment: @Damp its quite similar to the link you posted

Answer (score 2):

You could add an integer field called, for example, weight, and use it with ORDER BY clause.

this would be your original dataset:

```
Recnr | File        | weight
1     | img001.jpg  | 0
2     | img002.jpg  | 0
5     | img005.jpg  | 0
6     | img006.jpg  | 0
```

And to get one row higher, you make it weight less

```
Recnr | File        | weight
1     | img001.jpg  | 0
2     | img002.jpg  | -10
5     | img005.jpg  | 20
6     | img006.jpg  | 0
```

Then you SELECT * ORDER BY weight ASC to make the lightest records appear at the top.
And the result would be

```
Recnr | File        | weight
2     | img002.jpg  | -10
1     | img001.jpg  | 0
6     | img006.jpg  | 0
5     | img005.jpg  | 20
```

Comment: actually thats what im doing but the problem is how to swap weights? since Recnr is also swapping

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand your problem. To change weights use "UPDATE table_name SET weight=-10 WHERE Recnr=2". This will change only the weight of the second row only.

Comment: and how will i swap 2 weights at the same time? maybe 2 and 5 will change weights

Comment: @Joseph Lafuente: bassneck's main point is that you should not be using your primary key to sort by - you should have another weight field.  For swapping the weight values, ring0's solution works well.

Answer (score 2):

You can select the two values in two variables, and then update the table:

- Set the two variables

  ```
  SELECT @two:=File FROM mytable WHERE Recnr=2;
  SELECT @five:=File FROM mytable WHERE Recnr=5;
  ```
- Update the table

  ```
  UPDATE mytable SET File=@five WHERE Recnr=2;
  UPDATE mytable SET File=@two  WHERE Recnr=5;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

By adapting method 3 from the [answer to Swapping column values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649/swapping-column-values-in-mysql/559291#559291) I came up with this solution:

```
UPDATE your_table t1, your_table t2 SET
t1.File = (@temp:=t1.File),
t1.File = t2.File,
t2.File = @temp
WHERE t1.Recnr = 2 AND t2.Recnr = 5;
```

Comment: Yay! Worked perfectly for me!