# Do UPDATE statements set all values concurrently (at the same time)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Very simple question yet I could not find the answer.

Suppose I have table `var` with columns `foo` and `bar`, both of which are integers and **currently at 0**.

If I run:

`UPDATE var SET foo=foo+1, bar=foo+1`

Then what will be the value of `bar`? 1 or 2?

Does it change if I switch the order?

`UPDATE var SET bar=foo+1, foo=foo+1`

Comment: There is no incremental statement, therefore if foo = 0 then you will get 1, 1 in both columns.

Comment: What does an incremental statement look like? (if I want `bar` to be 2)

Comment: You would have to use a loop

Do until

set val = val + 1

end until


as a pseudo statement, i.e. in a stored procedure or in the main program. And yes, I agree this is a dupe.

Comment: I'm going to agree with the possible duplicate - but I'd be curious also why sqlfiddle seems to disagree.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffdb6/1  Something sqlfiddle-specific?

Comment: @joe maybe not a dupe then. The dupe is SQL Server and standard SQL. Maybe MYSQL behaves differently. I'll vote to reopen if closed as that is not the behaviour described in the possible dupe.

Comment: And from here looks as though it definitely is different http://stackoverflow.com/a/559291/73226

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As indicated by [Joe's SQL Fiddle comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989008/do-update-statements-set-all-values-concurrently-at-the-same-time#comment21051031_14989008), it does indeed matter what order the column updates are performed.  The MySQL documentation for [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) indicates this, stating that the expression for each column update will be evaluated in the order declared, and it always uses the "current" value of a column:

> If you access a column from the table to be updated in an expression, `UPDATE` uses the current value of the column. For example, the following statement sets `col1` to one more than its current value:
>
> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1;
> ```
>
> The second assignment in the following statement sets `col2` to the current (updated) `col1` value, not the original `col1` value. The result is that `col1` and `col2` have the same value. This behavior differs from standard SQL.
>
> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
> ```
>
> Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that assignments are carried out in any particular order.

So for `UPDATE var SET foo=foo+1, bar=foo+1`, `foo` will be set to `foo+1`, then the `bar` update will use the newly set value of `foo` in `foo+1`.

It may also be worthwhile to note that this behavior differs from the SQL standard, which indicates that all column updates should conceptually happen "at the same time".

Answer (score 2):

The order does matter in MySQL. Moreover, you can do the following:

```
update test set foo=foo+1, bar=foo+1, foo=bar+1;
```

BTW, here is another useful MySQL-specific trick:

```
insert into test (foo, bar) values ('some text', MD5(foo));
```

Answer (score 0):

take note - for postgresql the query executes with values at the start of the query, not the dynamically changing values while the query is executing

```
create table test (
field1 int2 default 0,
field2 int2 default 0
);


insert into test values (1, 2);


update test set field1 = field2, field2 = field1 +1;


select * from test;
```

Results:

```
field1, field2
    2,2
```

Answer (score -2):

foo=1, bar=1 regardless of order [edit: in MS-SQL.  (apparently my bad in MySQL)]

Comment: The SQL Fiddle link in the comments indicates that this is not the case in MySQL