# swapping values within the same column in mysql during update

Tags: mysql, sql-update

My table looks like this,

```
    RangeId    CellId  Some Coulmns more 
       101        1
       101        2
```

I ll get a list with `[101,2],[101,1]` now i have to swap cellId values in the above table. How to write an update query for this. I went through [Swapping column values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649/swapping-column-values-in-mysql) but this swaps between two coulmns. Any suggestion..

**EDIT**: I am swapping the cells in my app and i ll get two cell ids. I have two just swap 2 with 1 and 1 with 2 and rest of the values in the rows remains the same

**EDIT2**: The table doesnt have any Id column nor a primary key.

Comment: Are you trying to swap around the cellid values for rows with the same CellID values?  Having trouble understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Simon i am swapping the cells in my app and i ll get two cell ids. I have two just swap 2 with 1 and 1 with 2 and rest of the values in the rows remains the same

Comment: Ok so the ID is independent / PK (probably just getting confused from the use of "1" and "2" in multiple places)

Comment: @Simon Id is independent i wont use Id coulmn for the update ...

Comment: @Simon As of now i have list `[101,2],[101,1]`

Comment: RangeId and cellId i just need to swap the values say if get 2,1 and i have two swap cellids 1 with 2 and 2 with 1 .. Hope you get now what am i trying to do ..

Answer (score 0):

With your table as currently stated you cannot really do as you wish as there is no unique way to identify rows.  I advise that you step back and look at what you are trying to do as it feels like either a: it's not been thought through, or b: you've not given enough information for this to really be solved

If b:, please provide more information on this table and the tables it links to and precisely what you are trying to achieve (yes I know you want to swap 2 numeric values however without knowing more information about the tables / what can be used to select it is VERY hard to advise accurately)

**note** below was written for OPs original edit

This isn't a nice way to do it but it may get what you are after, it relies on ID being a PKID

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c48c/2

Comment: but my cellId coulmn is not a primary key.. It may not have unique value. For example RangedId = 102 the cellId coulmn may still have (1,2) ...

Comment: Without a method to identify single rows, you cannot do as you are trying to do any way but manually as far as I know.  Is there a primary key on this table that can be used?

Comment: thats what we dont have a primary key field in this table.

Comment: Then what is Id, does that link to another table?  Is this an n:m linking table?  I'm afraid past the above there's not much more I can say without further information.

Comment: Is there anything at all unique about this table?  Right now it seems you want to change from having 2 rows which contain (101,1),(101,2) to 2 rows which contain (101,1),(101,2).