# Data Transposition, SQL

Tags: sql

I have in my SQL table about 5000 rows.
I have two columns 'name1' and 'name2'. And now, tricky part. I have to data from 'name1' put into 'name2' and data from 'name2' should be in 'name1'... I know that I can make extra column just for this action but I have a feeling that is a better and faster way to do it.
Important part that I cannot do it for all the rows but for particular part (about 50%), simply for 'WHERE type = 'p' ' ;-)

Comment: I deleted my answer following your clarification...

Comment: Sorry that I firstly forgot about this part ;-) But your answer wasn't stupid. I just change columns names and later data from on of them just put into second (for this rows that I didn't want to affect second column was empty so I was able to do it). Although I'm still intereseting is there any way in SQL to make something like 'exchange' data from two columns ;-)

Comment: have a look on this one.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649/swapping-column-values-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use case-when to conditionally rename the columns:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN t.type = 'p' THEN t.name2 ELSE t.name1 END as name1,
    CASE WHEN t.type = 'p' THEN t.name1 ELSE t.name2 END as name2,
    t.type
FROM (your original select) t;
```