# updating mysql columns retrospectively using data from row

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update

We have just changed some of the functionality in one our web apps, and every row in one of tables needs to have new data added, the data is 8 character hash of the name value and the current timestamp.

I am trying to update 2 columns as we also need to swap to columns around,

```
    UPDATE projects 
SET uri_hash = (SELECT slug FROM projects WHERE id = 79), 
    slug = MD5(SHA1(CONCAT(
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, (
            SELECT name FROM projects WHERE id=79
        )
    ))
```

What I am doing wrong, basically I want the values of uri_hash to equal the slug column and then I want to MD5 and SHA1 encrypt the current timestamp and the name value and assign that to the slug.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the point #4 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/559291/4627632), and assuming id is your primary key in your table, the following should work:

```
UPDATE projects p1, projects p2 
SET p1.uri_hash = p1.slug, p1.slug=MD5(SHA1(CONCAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,p2.name) 
WHERE p1.id=p2.id;
```

Note, this will update all the rows of your table.