# SQL: Shift columns value to left if a NULL value

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that looks like below, with possible nulls in initial columns. I am looking to shift the columns to left in case a null is found so that all the categories align together.

Input:
[image]

Expected Output:
[image]

Below are the DDL statements:

```
CREATE TABLE CATEGORIES
(L1 varchar(255),
 L2 varchar(255),
 L3 varchar(255),
 L4 varchar(255)
);
```

Insert records:

```
INSERT INTO CATEGORIES
(L1, L2, L3, l4)
VALUES
('Womens Clothing' , 'Womens Accessories', 'View all Accessories', null );

INSERT INTO CATEGORIES
(L1, L2, L3, l4)
VALUES
(null , 'Womens Clothing', 'Womens Accessories', 'Bags');


INSERT INTO CATEGORIES
(L1, L2, L3, l4)
VALUES
(null , null, 'Mens Clothing', 'Shirts' );
```

I am quite new to SQL and quite not able to wrap my head around how to solve this

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I am using snowflake db. But if I get the mysql or postgres equivalent I should be able to manage.

Comment: you need the result in select query or do you want to update the source table ?

Comment: I just need it in a select query

Comment: Already answered here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874282/how-to-shift-column-values-in-mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to shift column values in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874282/how-to-shift-column-values-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lateral join, filter, and reaggregate:

```
select *
from categories c cross join lateral
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then val end) as l1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then val end) as l2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then val end) as l3,
             max(case when seqnum = 4 then val end) as l4
      from (select v.*, row_number() over (order by ord) as seqnum
            from (values (1, l1), (2, l2), (3, l3), (4, L4)
                 ) v(ord, val)
            where val is not null
           ) v
     ) v;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f8601cf627f1eb1b7df774ad353c048b) is a db<>fiddle using Postgres.

Or using arrays:

```
select (array_remove(array[l1, l2, l3, l4], NULL))[1] as l1,
       (array_remove(array[l1, l2, l3, l4], NULL))[2] as l2,
       (array_remove(array[l1, l2, l3, l4], NULL))[3] as l3,
       (array_remove(array[l1, l2, l3, l4], NULL))[4] as l4
from categories c;
```

I'm not sure which of these is easier for you to translate into Snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

Translating Gordon Linoff's second example to Snowflake works.

```
select (array_compact(array_construct(l1, l2, l3, l4)))[0]::varchar as l1,
       (array_compact(array_construct(l1, l2, l3, l4)))[1]::varchar as l2,
       (array_compact(array_construct(l1, l2, l3, l4)))[2]::varchar as l3,
       (array_compact(array_construct(l1, l2, l3, l4)))[3]::varchar as l4
from categories c;
```

Comment: Thanks, for the snowflake conversion!  Seems like `array_compact` is zero-indexed. So to extract l1 we should use array_compact(array_construct(l1, l2, l3, l4)))[0] and so on..