# How to swap two values of single column in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

This in not a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649/swapping-column-values-in-mysql). I want to swap values vertically while in other question swap is horizontally.

I have table Products:

```
id  |   holder_id
--------------- 
1   |   2       
2   |   2   
3   |   13  
4   |   13  
5   |   1       
6   |   12  
7   |   16      
8   |   20  
--------------
```

Where holder_id is reference to User id.
And table conversations:

```
id  |   user1   |   user2   |   product1    |   product2    
-------------------------------------------------------
..
2   |   12      |   2       |   6           |   2
```

---

What I want is to have a single statement to swap holder_id's for two products by conversation id. So for conversation id 2 it should look like this:

```
id  |   holder_id
--------------- 
1   |   2       
2   |   12  
3   |   13  
4   |   13  
5   |   1       
6   |   2   
7   |   16      
8   |   20  
--------------
```

So now the holder_id's for id 2 and 6 are swapped.

I have tried:

```
UPDATE products as p
INNER JOIN conversations as c
ON p.id=c.product1
SET p.holder_id=c.user2
WHERE c.id=2;
```

and with this I manage two do this:

```
id  |   holder_id
--------------- 
1   |   2       
2   |   2   //still have to change this
3   |   13  
4   |   13  
5   |   1       
6   |   2   // changed this
7   |   16      
8   |   20  
--------------
```

Now I have to do onother join to same table and I cant understand how to do that.

Comment: Do you need to swap? It looks like you have all that is needed to just set the values. It would be 2 queries `UPDATE Products SET holder_id = 2 WHERE id = 2` and `UPDATE Products SET holder_id = 13 WHERE id = 4`. Doing a swap is usually for larger sets of data where the number/values are dynamic

Comment: Well the problem is that before doing swap I have only both products id's. I actually dont have holder_id's. So I would have to query for them and then do 2 queries you suggested.

Comment: After tour comment I realized that there could be better way for doing this. I edited question with extra details and where I am stuck