# Switch Shipping and Billing Values From Database

Tags: database, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce website. I had changed translation files for checkout page to customer experience. I had used shipping fields as billing fields and billing fields as shipping fields. Now I want to change them to normal status.
I want to update database values as below

```
shipping_name = billing_name
and 
billing_name = shipping_name
```

etc.
What is the best way for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found solution that.
Wordpress use MySQL so we can use MySQL commands. 
This topic is answer for me : 
[Swapping column values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649/swapping-column-values-in-mysql)

Answer (score -1):

If you update the version of Woo-commerce, it'll update the fields as well. In case, if you have extended the class to the child theme, you need to do it manually using the reverse process which you have followed to make this change.