# Swap Short description with long description for Woocommerce products

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I have to swap short product descriptions with long product descriptions in 200+ products in Woocommerce. Do you know any fast ways to do this? Database query, Better Search&Replace plugin? :-)

/swapping it on the front end side (how they are displayed on product page) is not enough - I need to map them in one module which doesn't support short desc./

All answers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make always a database backup. Then you can try this simple SQL query that will swap product description with product short description on all WooCommerce published products *(check that your WordPress database table start with `wp_` before)*:

```
UPDATE wp_post AS p 
SET p.post_content=(@temp:=p.post_content), 
    p.post_content = p.post_excerpt, 
    p.post_excerpt = @temp 
WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
AND  p.post_status = 'publish';
```

Related: [Swapping column values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649/swapping-column-values-in-mysql/559291#559291)

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62686970/3744182) by [LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec) needs one modification.  Specifically, the first line should be `wp_posts` not `wp_post`:

```
UPDATE wp_posts AS p
```