# Swapping column values in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

In my `PostgreSQL` database, I have a table with two text values, `t1` and `t2`:

```
|   id   |   t1   |   t2   |  
|   1    |  abcd  |   xyz  |  
|   2    |  aazz  |   rst  |  
|   3    |  fgh   | qwerty |
```

I would like to swap the values of the columns `t1` and `t2` for every row in the table in a way that, using the above example, this would be the result:

```
|   id   |   t1   |   t2   |
|   1    |  xyz   |   abcd |
|   2    |  rst   |   aazz |
|   3    | qwerty |   fgh  |
```

Also, let's suppose the values from all rows with id=4 onwards (4, 5, 6...) are already correct, is it possible to filter which rows I want to swap?
I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649/swapping-column-values-in-mysql) (for MySQL Databases) but none of the solutions worked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
select * from swapit;
 id |  t1   |   t2
----+-------+--------
  1 | abcd  | xyz
  2 | aazz  | rst
  3 | fgh   | qwerty
  4 | first | second
  5 | first | second
(5 rows)

update swapit set t1 = t2, t2 = t1 where id <= 3;
UPDATE 3

select * from swapit order by id;
 id |   t1   |   t2   
----+--------+--------
  1 | xyz    | abcd
  2 | rst    | aazz
  3 | qwerty | fgh
  4 | first  | second
  5 | first  | second
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Everybody forgets about tasty PostgreSQL feature: `set (t1, t2) = (t2, t1)`

Comment: Worth mentioning that @abelisto 's comment is for the normal [`UPDATE`-statemtent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html). I searched for a PL/PGSQL-statement `SET` for assigning multiple variables at once, which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: @taffit `select t1, t2 into t2, t1;` If you mean C-style `a = b = 1;` then yes, pl/sql based on Pascal/Ada syntax where the assignment statement does not returns value.

Comment: @abelisto Correct, thanks for the clarification. Indeed I checked for a PL/PGSQL `SET`-command, which doesn't exist. Using `SELECT ... INTO ...` helps with the swap, while the syntax you mentioned works perfectly on an `UPDATE ... SET ...`-statement.

Answer (score 22):

That's a simple UPDATE:

```
update the_table
  set t1 = t2, 
      t2 = t1
where id < 4;
```

Unlike MySQL, Postgres does this correctly.